# ArrayList automatically duplicates items in it

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-viewpager2

I have created a variable `private var deals=ArrayList<Deals>()` in a `fragment` and I have set a click listener in the `onCerateView()` like the following.

```
binding.tvAllDeals.setOnClickListener {
        viewAllDeals()
    }
```

So that it will trigger the following method

```
private fun viewAllDeals(){
    val intent = Intent(context,ViewAllDealsActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("details",deals)
    Log.d("Tag2", "Size is ${deals.size}")
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

I have the following function to get the data from the `firestore` and then I save the result in the variable 'deals'. However, whenever I click the 'tvAllDeals' it shows many images, when I check the size of the 'deals' using `Log.d` 'Tag1' always shows the correct size, which is 3, whereas 'Tag2' show some random numbers like 6, 9, 24. I try to find out why this is happening but I didn't get any idea. The variable 'deals' is not used anywhere else other than declaring and initializing, to assign the value and to pass it in the 'viewAllDeals()'

```
private fun getDeals() {
    FirestoreClass().getDeals(
        onSuccess = { list ->
            Result.success(list)
            successDeals(list)  ///// THIS FUNCTION WILL SHOW THE IMAGES IN A VIEWPAGER
            deals.clear()
            deals=list
            Log.d("Tag1", "Size is ${deals.size}")
        },
        onFailure = {
        }
    )
}
```

Edit:

NOTE: 'Tag3' also shows correct array size like 'Tag1'. However,

```
private fun successDeals(list: ArrayList<Deals>) {

   Log.d("Tag3", "Size is ${deals.size}")

    if (list.size > 0) {
        binding.vpDeals.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val adapter = DealsAdapter(binding.vpDeals,requireContext(), list)
        binding.vpDeals.adapter = adapter
        binding.vpDeals.orientation = ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL

        sliderHandle= Handler()
        sliderRun= Runnable {
            binding.vpDeals.currentItem=binding.vpDeals.currentItem+1
        }

        binding.vpDeals.registerOnPageChangeCallback(
            object :ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback(){
                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                    super.onPageSelected(position)

                    sliderHandle.removeCallbacks(sliderRun)
                    sliderHandle.postDelayed(sliderRun,4000)
                }
            }
        )

    } else {
        binding.vpDeals.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

Comment: My recommendation is to never combine `var` with ArrayList or MutableList. Making it mutable in two different ways makes it more complicated to work with and harder to avoid bugs. And if you can choose between a `var` `List` and a `val` `MutableList`, the `var` `List` is less error-prone. It makes it impossible for you to accidentally mutate a list instance that some other class like your ViewPager is depending on, or to forget to clear a list before adding items, etc. (Forgetting to clear the list somewhere might be what's causing your problem.)

Comment: Can you show the `successDeals` function?

Comment: Added in the question, please check, thanks.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Can you find the mistake in my code?

Comment: I don't see specifically what is causing your issue, but I see numerous code smells. 1) `Result.success(list)` creates a Result object and doesn't do anything with it so this line should be removed. 2) `deals` is both a `var` and an `ArrayList` so it is mutable in two different ways. 3) You clear the list referred to by `deals` before reassigning it. Since you are passing mutable lists around, this can have unexpected side effects because who knows what other classes are relying on that list. What is the point of clearing it? 4) `successDeals` demands specificallly a List of type ArrayList...

Comment: ...for no reason because it's not mutating it or doing anything demanding a specific behavior of the list under the hood. 5) Creating a handler inside `successDeals` so every time it's called, the old Handler is lost. This is very error prone. You might think your click listener is stopping an old runnable when it's not because it's looking at a different handler than the one used previously.

Comment: 6) Creating an Adapter inisde `successDeals`. Adapters should only be created and assigned once (usually in `Activity.onCreate` or `Fragment.onViewCreated`), but this will recreate an Adapter every time `successDeals` is called, wasting all the formerly created views and runnables.

Comment: OK, when I removed Handler and the Runnable parts of code from the method successDeals(list: ArrayList<Deals>) and from the adapter class 'DealsAdapter'. The items in the list don't duplicate. However, that doesn't solve my problem as I used  Handler and the Runnable to make the image slide in the `ImageView`.

What I still don't understand is, I used 'deals=list' only within the method 'getDeals()' and 'getDeals()' is only called in `onResume()`. Then how come the value of 'deals' is overwritten (I do not reassign its value anywhere) only when I use those Handler and Runnable?

Comment: Could be something DealsAdapter does with the list. These are the dangers of passing mutable lists between classes. Very hard to track down bugs. I don't think you need to eliminate your handler and runnable. Make them `val`s and create them at their declaration sites.

Comment: Making them `val` didn't fix the issue. I used an alternative method to overcome the issue. But, I think that's not really a solution to the problem. Now the alternative that I used is instead of `ViewPager2` I used an `ImageSlider` as the issue was caused due to Handler and Runnable, but that was required to make the images slideable automatically in the `ViewPager2`. Thanks for your time and effort.